# How to commit to a git repository using libgit2?

Tags: c++, c, libgit2

Since there is no copy-paste example for creating a commit without using files on disk with [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/) [as far as I can tell](https://www.google.ro/search?q=commit%20to%20a%20git%20repository%20using%20libgit2) I thought I should add one.

Don't forget that libgit2 is in full development at this time (March 2013) so have a look at official documentation and source code, as new features are added daily:

- [libgit2 API](http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD)
- headers are very well commented - [here's an example](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/HEAD/include/git2/clone.h#L99-103)
- [extensive tests](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/tree/master/tests) may be a source of inspiration
- there are some [official examples](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/tree/master/examples), [general.c](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/master/examples/general.c) is a good place to start
- inspiration may be found in [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) - here are [some tests](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/ObjectDatabaseFixture.cs)

Comment: While it's not neat code (I am refactoring), I did accomplish exactly that. I inject the files I want to commit directly into the index and commit them without writing to the disk. See the [Gitorium repository](https://github.com/MagnaX-Tech/Gitorium/blob/master/src/bin/cmd_setup.c).

Comment: Gives me a 404 error. Is a private repository?

Comment: The name of the organisation changed, and the URL was updated. [This](https://github.com/MagnaX-Soft/Gitorium/blob/master/src/bin/cmd_setup.c) is the correct URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool addGitCommit ( 
  git_repository * repo, git_signature * sign, 
  const char * content, int content_sz,
  const char * message )
{
  int rc;              /* return code for git_ functions */
  git_oid oid_blob;    /* the SHA1 for our blob in the tree */
  git_oid oid_tree;    /* the SHA1 for our tree in the commit */
  git_oid oid_commit;  /* the SHA1 for our initial commit */
  git_blob * blob;     /* our blob in the tree */
  git_tree * tree_cmt; /* our tree in the commit */
  git_treebuilder * tree_bld;  /* tree builder */
  bool b = false;

  /* create a blob from our buffer */
  rc = git_blob_create_frombuffer( 
        &oid_blob,
        repo, 
        content, 
        content_sz );
  if ( rc == 0 ) { /* blob created */
    rc = git_blob_lookup( &blob, repo, &oid_blob );
    if ( rc == 0 ) { /* blob created and found */
      rc = git_treebuilder_create( &tree_bld, NULL );
      if ( rc == 0 ) { /* a new tree builder created */
        rc = git_treebuilder_insert( 
              NULL, 
              tree_bld, 
              "name-of-the-file.txt", 
              &oid_blob, 
              GIT_FILEMODE_BLOB );
        if ( rc == 0 ) { /* blob inserted in tree */
          rc = git_treebuilder_write( 
                &oid_tree, 
                repo, 
                tree_bld );
          if ( rc == 0 ) { /* the tree was written to the database */
            rc = git_tree_lookup(
                  &tree_cmt, repo, &oid_tree );
            if ( rc == 0 ) { /*we've got the tree pointer */  
              rc = git_commit_create(
                    &oid_commit, repo, "HEAD",
                    sign, sign, /* same author and commiter */
                    NULL, /* default UTF-8 encoding */
                    message,
                    tree_cmt, 0, NULL );
              if ( rc == 0 ) {
                b = true;
              }
              git_tree_free( tree_cmt );
            }
          }
        }
        git_treebuilder_free( tree_bld );
      }
      git_blob_free( blob );
    }
  }
  return b;
}
```

The repository comes from `git_repository_init()` or `git_repository_open()`.
The signature comes from `git_signature_now()` or `git_signature_new()`.

The function updates the HEAD for current branch.

If you do a `git status` after the function executes you will notice that the file `name-of-the-file.txt` appears as being deleted. That is because the function does not create an actual file, only an entry in the git database.

Also, note the last arguments of `git_commit_create()`. 0 and NULL means that this is the first (root) commit. For all other there should be at least a parent commit specified, maybe obtained using `git_commit_lookup()`.

---

I'm just learning these things. Please improve this answer if you know better.

Comment: Something **[similar](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/ObjectDatabaseFixture.cs#L81-107)** also exists in LibGit2Sharp (.Net bindings).

Comment: Some discussions have also been held regarding the addition of a feature which would ease the creation of commits without involving the index nor the working directory. It should land in libgit2 post v1.0

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question so that the links are more visible than at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: So, once you create the commit, are there any remaining steps that should be taken? For example, do I need to write this commit to disk? Update the index to a new index? Update HEAD and/or the current branch to point to this commit, etc? (Because right now it doesn't seem to do anything..)

Comment: Also, --sorry--, I'm a little confused: what is the content being passed in to the commit that's getting put into our blob? Shouldn't the "content" of the commit just be the state of the current index? Thanks for the clarifications!

Comment: The content is an array of chars. Any content, say ```const char * data = "abcsef";``` That particular content is associated with ```name-of-the-file.txt``` and, after that, since the file does not appear on the disk, from the point of view of git it is deleted.

Comment: Take a look at http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/commit/git_commit_create; HEAD in our case is updated to point to this commit: ```const char * update_ref If not NULL, name of the reference that will be updated to point to this commit. If the reference is not direct, it will be resolved to a direct reference. Use "HEAD" to update the HEAD of the current branch and make it point to this commit. If the reference doesn't exist yet, it will be created.```

Comment: Please note that the style in this code is *terrible*. The idea is to check `rc` for every call and handle the error, this code makes it very hard to follow what's happening.

Comment: @iharob Care to make a pastebin / gist version that you feel is more explicit / appropriate / conforms to main-stream styles? I could then replace posted code.

Comment: @TNick You can fix it! Just use `goto` instead of so many nested `if`'s. Think about it, which one is worst? A good `goto` that clearly takes you to the cleanup (repeatable) part of the function or, the convoluted nested `if`s that are so hard to understand.

Comment: @iharob I probably could, sure, maybe even using a `for(;;) { if (...) break; }` pattern; it has been a long time since I posted this and I learned a lot since then; but I was inviting YOU to step to the next level: not only point the flaw but actually fix the flaw. What do you say tho this challenge? :)

Comment: @TNick it's not a challenge and I'll be glad to, I actually want to. But right now I have not time. I will.