# Deleting a file from git repository using libgit2

Tags: c++, c, libgit2

Say you have a file in a git repository:

- a.txt

What APIs should be used to create a commit that removes that file?
For example in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711444/how-to-commit-to-a-git-repository-using-libgit2) the file is committed without creating it on disk. Is it now possible to remove that file without using the index (stage area)?

I was expecting a similar flow, maybe creating a `git_tree_entry` for the tree builder, but that does not seem to be the case. `git_reference_list()` does not list files, so there's a dead end. Also searching the sources for delete and remove got me no success.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing a file is similar to adding a file - you remove the index entry to stage the delete, then you can create a commit from the index.

You probably want to use `git_index_remove_bypath`, which will remove the file from the index *and* resolve any conflicts that file had.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a copy-paste example; for `getLastCommit()` see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717625/how-to-get-the-last-commit-from-head-in-a-git-repository-using-libgit2/15717626#15717626).

```
bool commitStage ( 
    git_repository * repo, git_signature * sign,
    const char * message )
{
  bool b = false;
  int rc;
  git_index * repo_idx;   /* the stage area for our repository */
  git_oid oid_idx_tree;   /* the SHA1 for the tree generated from index */
  git_oid oid_commit;     /* the SHA1 for our commit */
  git_tree * tree_cmt;    /* tree generated from index */
  git_commit * parent_commit;/* most recent commit in the head */

  parent_commit = getLastCommit( repo );
  if ( parent_commit != NULL )
  { /* we have the parent commit */
    rc = git_repository_index( &repo_idx, repo );
    if ( rc == 0 )
    { /* we now have the index (stage area) structure in repo_idx */
      git_index_read(repo_idx);
      /* the stage area may be altered here with functions like 
        git_index_add_bypath();
        git_index_remove_bypath();
        */

      /* by writing the index we get the SHA1 of the tree */
      rc = git_index_write_tree( &oid_idx_tree, repo_idx );
      if ( rc == 0 )
      {
        rc = git_tree_lookup(
              &tree_cmt, repo, &oid_idx_tree );
        if ( rc == 0 )
        { /* the actual tree structure; create a commit from it */
          rc = git_commit_create(
                &oid_commit, repo, "HEAD",
                sign, sign, NULL,
                message,
                tree_cmt, 1, (const git_commit**)&parent_commit );
          if ( rc == 0 )
          {
            b = true;
          }
        }
      }
      git_index_free( repo_idx );
    }
    git_commit_free( parent_commit );
  }
  return b;
}
```

Comment: please explain the -1, otherwise it's in vain, really. Help the one searching by pointing out the mistake so that I can fix it.