# How to get the last commit from HEAD in a git repository using libgit2?

Tags: c++, c, libgit2

Since there is no copy-paste example for getting last commit with [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com/) I thought I should add one. The examples in libgit2 make extensive use of `git_oid_fromstr()` ...

Don't forget that libgit2 is in full development at this time (March 2013) so have a look at official documentation and source code, as new features are added daily:

- [liggit2 API](http://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD)
- headers are very well commented - [here's an example](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/HEAD/include/git2/clone.h#L99-103)
- [extensive tests](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/tree/development/tests-clar) may be a source of inspiration
- there are some [official examples](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/tree/development/examples), [general.c](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/development/examples/general.c) is a good place to start
- inspiration may be found in [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) - here are [some tests](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/ObjectDatabaseFixture.cs)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
git_commit * getLastCommit ( git_repository * repo )
{
  int rc;
  git_commit * commit = NULL; /* the result */
  git_oid oid_parent_commit;  /* the SHA1 for last commit */

  /* resolve HEAD into a SHA1 */
  rc = git_reference_name_to_id( &oid_parent_commit, repo, "HEAD" );
  if ( rc == 0 )
  {
    /* get the actual commit structure */
    rc = git_commit_lookup( &commit, repo, &oid_parent_commit );
    if ( rc == 0 )
    {
      return commit;
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

You will need to call `git_commit_free()` once you are done with it.