# LibGit2 Commit example

Tags: git

I am trying to use LibGit2, and I 'm stuck in commit. I 've tried  [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15711444/how-to-commit-to-a-git-repository-using-libgit2) which works only for the "initial" commit. For next commits, it fails with -15 "current tip is not the first parent".

Two questions:

1. How do I know If i need an initial commit ?
2. How do I perform a non-initial commit?

Thx.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How do I know If i need an initial commit ?

You can check [git_repository_head_unborn()](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/repository/git_repository_head_unborn) to see if HEAD points at a reference or not.

> How do I perform a non-initial commit?

You need to supply the index to be committed.  This is easiest done with [git_repository_index()](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/repository/git_repository_index).  However, the index must be supplied as a tree.  The confusingly named [git_index_write_tree()](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/index/git_index_write_tree) will write the index to a tree for you.

To get the parent(s), use [git_oid_fromstr()](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/oid/git_oid_fromstr) to get an object id from a hash or [git_reference_name_to_id()](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/reference/git_reference_name_to_id) to get it from a reference name such as "HEAD".  Then use [git_commit_lookup()](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/commit/git_commit_lookup) to get the commit object(s) from the oids.

Then pass them into [git_commit_create()](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/commit/git_commit_create) or [git_commit_create_v()](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/#HEAD/group/commit/git_commit_create_v).  Using git_commit_create_v() avoids having to make a list of git_commit pointers, just pass the commits in as arguments like `printf()`.

There is a [good example in ex/general.c](https://libgit2.github.com/libgit2/ex/HEAD/general.html#section-Writing_Commits) which does a better job explaining all the steps than I will.  I also like to use Git::Raw, the Perl wrapper around libgit2, as an example.  Look at [the .xs files](https://metacpan.org/source/JACQUESG/Git-Raw-0.50/xs) (which are basically C).

Here is an untested example of committing the index to HEAD.  I'm assuming you already have the author, committer and repo.

```
git_oid tree_id, parent_id, commit_id;
git_tree *tree;
git_commit *parent;
git_index *index;

/* Get the index and write it to a tree */
git_repository_index(&index, repo);
git_index_write_tree(tree, index);

/* Get HEAD as a commit object to use as the parent of the commit */
git_reference_name_to_id(parent_id, repo, "HEAD");
git_commit_lookup(&parent, repo, parent_id);

/* Do the commit */
git_commit_create_v(
    commit_id,
    repo,
    "HEAD",     /* The commit will update the position of HEAD */
    author,
    committer,
    NULL,       /* UTF-8 encoding */
    message,
    tree,       /* The tree from the index */
    1,          /* Only one parent */
    parent      /* No need to make a list with create_v */
);
```

Comment: The first answer is good and working, thanks, but about the oid. Where should I have put a reference name in order to get a git_oid for it? How should I create a tree and put it in the list of the trees?

Comment: @Michael I've updated the answer to cover how to get the tree and parent in more detail.

Comment: Don't check `git_repository_is_empty`, check to see if your `HEAD` is pointing to a born branch or not with `git_repository_head_unborn`.  Otherwise you will try to query parents in a non-empty repo where you are on an unborn branch (from `git checkout --orphan <branch>`).

Comment: How do you separate the commit name and commit description if all we have is one field for the message?

Comment: @AaronFranke Commits don't have a name, it's just the first line of the message. Put a blank line between the name and body.