# How to commit from the given files?

Tags: libgit2

I need to use libgit2 to implement the "git commit -F ..." command.

The code below will commit 1.txt and 2.txt:

```
git_libgit2_init();

git_repository* pRepository;
git_index* pIndex;
git_oid oidTree, oidCommitted;
git_tree* pTree;
git_signature* pSignature;

git_repository_init(&pRepository, "C:\\Temp", false);
git_repository_index(&pIndex, pRepository);
git_index_add_bypath(pIndex, "1.txt");
git_index_add_bypath(pIndex, "2.txt");
git_index_write(pIndex);
git_index_write_tree(&oidTree, pIndex);
git_tree_lookup(&pTree, pRepository, &oidTree);
git_signature_now(&pSignature, "My name", "My email");
git_commit_create(&oidCommitted, pRepository, "refs/heads/master",
    pSignature, pSignature, NULL, "Initial commit with 1.txt", pTree, 0, NULL);
git_signature_free(pSignature);
git_tree_free(pTree);
git_index_free(pIndex);
git_repository_free(pRepository);

git_libgit2_shutdown();
```

How to change my code to implement:

```
git add 1.txt 2.txt
git commit 1.txt -m "Initial commit with 1.txt"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LibGit2 Commit example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27672722/libgit2-commit-example)

Comment: No, it's different. I had read that one.

Comment: Don't add `2.txt` to the index before creating the commit ? As you don't describe the mismatch between what you're expecting and what your code ends up doing, it's pretty hard to say what is actually wrong…

Comment: I need to pick up added files to commit. The difference between `git add 1.txt 2.txt`+`git commit 1.txt` and `git add 1.txt`+`git commit` is `2.txt` has added status and can be committed later.

Comment: Then there's no direct way to do that, mostly by design. `libgit2` is usually lower-level than what's considered git "porcelain", and since you can do what you want by doing operations in a different order, it saves some implementation effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to come up with a tree object to pass to `git_commit_create` without modifying the repository's index. There are several ways to do that. The easiest is to create your own in-memory index and use that instead of the repository's index. Essentially, do something like this:

```
...
git_repository_init(&repo, ...); // same as before
git_index_new(&index); // create in-memory index
git_index_read_tree(index, headTree); // initialize to the current HEAD
git_index_add_by_path(index, "1.txt"); // update the nominated file(s)
git_index_write_tree_to(&oid, index, repo); // write the tree into the repo
git_tree_lookup(&tree, repo, &oid); // same as before
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method One:**

Either modify the repository's index to reflect what you want to commit: call `git_index_add` to put the data for 2.txt back in the index, then remove it again after creating the tree for the commit.

**Method Two:**

Duplicate the repository's index as a temporary, in-memory index and mutate that one, adding the 1.txt back in. Then create the tree from that index instead of the repository's index. `git_index_add_by_path` will fail when operating on an in-memory index. It can’t find that path, it has no concept of where to look for it.
`Git_index_add_by_path` works by reading the file on disk to create a `git_index_entry`. It’s a convenience function.
Instead, you can use `git_index_add` with the index entry data.